# How can I remove a dynamically added node from memory?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, linked-list, nodes

I have a node in a linked list defined as:

```
class Node {
public:
    Node* next = nullptr;
    int value;
};
```

I am inserting nodes into the list as:

```
void insertNode(Node* &head, int value) {

    Node* newNode = new Node;
    newNode->value = value;
    newNode->next = head;

    head = newNode;
}
```

I want to remove some node in that list in another function

```
void deleteNode(Node* head) {
    // ...
}
```

How can I remove that now unused node from memory?

Comment: Btw; you *could* just use `std::list` for a linked list (or in most cases, even better, `std::vector`) - reinventing the wheel is rarely worth it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd remove a node by 1) `delete`ing it. 2) adjusting the previous node to point to the one following the deleted node (or `nullptr` if the deleted node was the last one).

Comment: Note that you have to have the pointer to that previous node in singly linked-list.

Comment: @LogicStuff of course. How to do that I'll leave as an exercise for OP.

Comment: So something like:
       
delete curr;
prev->next = curr->next;

I'm trying this right now, but I don't understanding why I'm still able to access "curr->next" if I've deleted "curr"?

Comment: @CuriousProgrammer70184 "I don't understanding why I'm still able to access "curr->next" if I've deleted "curr"?" - you are *not*; doing so would be Undefined Behaviour (even if it *seems to work* in your specific case) - don't delete something before you are done with it.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Ok got it. So my being able to access it is just a fluke then? And the way it should be formatted is: prev->next = curr->next; delete curr;

Comment: @CuriousProgrammer70184 yes.

Comment: Accessing the pointer that points to memory that was freed is undefined behavior. There is no guarantee what is returned. The memory could have been reused in a different allocation or even returned back to the OS.